# SwiftUI reordering animation with ForEach does not work with indexes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to make it so that when list of items is shuffled the views in Vstack make a reordering animation.

I made it work with the code below

```
VStack {
    ForEach(viewModel.game.cards) { card in
        CardView(card: card)
    }
         
    Button("Randomize") {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
            self.viewModel.newGame()
        }
    }
}
```

But when I slightly change for each to work with indexes like so

```
ForEach(0..<viewModel.game.cards.count) { card in
    CardView(card: self.viewModel.game.cards[card])
}
```

It stops working. Why is that happening? My guess is this because the Card is a struct and it is a copy on write. But I still don't understand exactly why this is happening.

Also this is a dumbed down example and foreach with indexes looks wrong here but in the actual implementation I need to get items by index. So how can I do this and make the animation work?

Comment: I might be wrong but this sounds a lot like the swift UI Stanford lecture assignment. Maybe ask a more generic question instead of getting help for this assignment.

Comment: The issue is in unique identifiers, in the first case both views unique independently of order, in second case after switching indexes they unidentified.

Comment: @DerickMathews this is indeed from Stanford course, but unfortunately I am not a Stanford student and I watch this course on YouTube so this is the only place to ask for help. So I don't have to do this assignment I am just curious of the behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I can only answer your question why does it not work anymore:
It does not longer animate the changes, because your ForEach no longer knows that you shuffled the array. Swift only sees the indicies and the indicies stayed the same as well as the count of the array.

If you change the following in your ForEach

```
Foreach(cards.indicies, id: \.self)
```

You will see that the List is animating again, but not as before. Because the Forach only knows that this Element in the array is replaced and not the entire Array.

**Edit:** Here is a solution that might help you, but because I don't know what you want to achieve exactly with getItem I am not sure if it fits your problem. I hope it leads you in the right direction.

```
    struct TestView: View {
    @State var cards = [Card(), Card(), Card(), Card()]
    var cardsByIndex: [Card] {
        //getItemByIndexMethod
        var c = [Card]()
        for i in cards.indices {
            c.append(cards[i])
        }
        return c
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(cardsByIndex) { card in
                CardView(card: card)
            }
            Button("Randomize") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    self.cards.shuffle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    let card: Card
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(card.name)
    }
}

struct Card: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name = String("ABCDE".shuffled())
}
```

Comment: I see. So there is no way to make it work with indices? What if I have a grid (Vstack of hstask)? I need to get items by index there.

Comment: No I dont think you can make it work directly with indicies, but i edited my answer for a possible solotion. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out. I am trying to achieve a reordering animation in a grid when you shuffle it. And by default it does not work if the grid is vstack of hstacks (I'm which case you need 2 foreach's that operate on indexes). It only works if items in the grid layed out manually by coordinates(one foreach on elements). Anyways I think with swiftui2 Grid element I think it will work by default.